# Laravel autoloader

Tags: php, laravel

First I had my project running in Ubuntu, but I didn't have enough diskspace. So I made a new environment with more diskspace and I tried to transfer my project to the new environment.

I use virtualbox with Xubuntu 16.04.

PHP version 7.2.3

Composer update or install doesn't work. vendor directory is missing.

[What am I doing wrong? screenshot of website.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ajg91.png)

Comment: did you composer update / install ? if still the problem persists, try to set a new installation of Laravel with composer in a new project and chek if the problem persists

Comment: Your code is not being processed. Make sure PHP is installed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP code is not being executed, instead code shows on the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121495/php-code-is-not-being-executed-instead-code-shows-on-the-page)

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I'll try both solutions! I'll let you know if that works.

Comment: When I run the command "composer update or install" it's saying that the vendor directory is missing.

Comment: I have PHP installed version 7.2.3

Comment: You mentioned your vendor directory is missing. Did you include it when migrating?

Comment: I guess not. I uploaded my project folder from the old environment to gitlab and in the new environment I did git clone. So its possible that the vendor directory wasn't stored in gitlab?

Comment: you were right Ilva. Vendor wasn't transported to gitlab. I'll try to transfer the vendor directory manually and see if that does the trick.

Comment: I transfered the vendor file. But I still get the same screen as before.